# I alway have to put 'npx' before I a command?

Tags: javascript, node.js, nestjs

Yesterday, I did something wrong, so that today I alway have to put 'npx' before any command.
For example:

```
npx nest new project-name
npx tsc app
```

Instead of

```
nest new project-name
tsc app
```

Is there any way to fix that problem. Thank you so much.

Comment: only by installing those tools (nest and tsc) locally in your project

Comment: to use `nest` and `tsc` without `npx` (or `yarn`) you'll need to install them globally. I don't recommend this tho.

Answer (score 1):

you need to install typescript globally otherwise you need to run `npx` all the time. To install them globally use `npm install typescript -g`.